# Enqueuing chained queueable instances that trigger deployment jobs don't perform deployment

Tags: callout, future, queueable-apex

I've got problem with executing deployment jobs inside queueable instance.

**Background**:

- Exchange rates data is divided between two endpoints a and b. That's why I need to make a callout twice.
- `requestExchangeRates` future method that fetches exchange rates and performs `enqueueDeployment` to update/create exchange rate metadata records.

```
public class ExchangeRatesService implements Queueable {
    
    private String tableName;
    private Boolean secondCall;
    
    public ExchangeRatesService(String tableName, Boolean secondCall) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.secondCall = secondCall;
    }
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        if(secondCall) return;
        if(tableName == 'a') {
            requestExchangeRates(tableName);
            if(!secondCall) {
                System.enqueueJob(new ExchangeRatesService('b',true));   
            }
        } else if(tableName == 'b') {
            requestExchangeRates(tableName);
            if(!secondCall) {
                System.enqueueJob(new ExchangeRatesService('a',true));   
            }            
        } else {
            //Unrecognized 
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**: No deployment job is performed, all related queueable and future jobs are completed successfully.
How to perform this scenario? is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by a "deployment job"?

Comment: How certain are you that the `requestExchangeRates` future method ran in addition to the  re-enqueued `ExchangeRatesService` Queueable job? Normally you want to avoid multiple async branches coming out of a Queueable Job execution. Salesforce will explicitly stop you from launching multiple queueable jobs and may be putting the future method in the same limitation. I've definitely  long chains of *single* child queueables and future methods in this way.

Comment: Does an anonymous Apex call to `requestExchangeRates('a');` produce the expected custom metadata deployment?